# Sending the same email for different groups

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I have a data extension with the base that I want to send a email to them.
But I want to send to some part of them at hour X and for other part at hour Y. Actually, I have 24 segments, each one for each hour of the day.
How can I set up a schedule send for a newsletter without the need to created 24 emails?
I can create the 24 segments/data extensions/queries, and them someone only goes and update the emails that wants to send?
I did Journey Builder automation that do this, but it's taking too long too populate the automation (~500k emails).

Comment: Are these segments filtered or random? If random, you could try send throttling (http://support.fanmailmarketing.com/entries/25211647-Send-Throttling or https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/guided_send/#section_4)

Answer (score 1):

Technically you could do the following if the metering doesnt work:

Step 1 - Insert records from your DE records into Send DE 2 where mailed flag = N

> SELECT TOP 4 PERCENT * FROM FIRSTDE;

Step 2 - Fire a trigger which sends to everyone in Send DE 2

Step 3 - Update your DE and set a mailed flag = Y

Repeat each hour - this will send to 4% every hour (this doesnt equal 100% but it is close). You could also replace Step 3 - and just have the mailed flag in your first DE and update that.

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  You could easily accomplish this with two Data Extensions, one Content, one User-Initiated Send, one Automation set to run every hour and two queries.